# Make USSD Call from the application

Tags: blackberry

i have made code to make USSD call:

```
PhoneArguments call = new PhoneArguments(PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, "*004*"+
_String1+
"*"+
_String2+
"#"
);
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, call);
```

**the app make the call and send the USSD request and show the response without any problems.** 
but it gives an error message with "cannot connect to ....", how to hide this error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure there's no duplication